# Best solutions for tree in doctrine with extension

Tags: doctrine-orm, tree, doctrine-extensions

I am finding Best solutions for tree in doctrine with extension.
I need tree:

- in one table
- with multiple roots
- add onne root item to another root item
- tree items need order (weight) also roots
- create list with one select and without recursion

I try from this extension: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/tree.md

nested
- I can not order root items

closure
- not good idea , need 2 tables

materializedPath
- maybe bes way but do not have order (weight)

Does anyone have experience how to solve it?

Comment: Why do you need multiple roots? I've had problems with that too, but decided to have just one 'pseudo' root and consider the first childs as 'root'.

Comment: So because I don't want `pseudo` root, this record I never use.

Comment: Did you find solution ?